# Ausgenommen den öffentlichen Veranstaltungen ist es bekannt, dass er immer den Vorsitzenden geholfen hat

Tags: translation, preposition, grammatical-case

> Ausgenommen den öffentlichen Veranstaltungen ist es bekannt, dass er immer den Vorsitzenden geholfen hat.

Ist in diesem Satz *»ausgenommen«* richtig?

Comment: Was soll der Satz denn ausdrücken? Ohne mehr Kontext kann die Frage leicht as "proofreading request" geschlossen.

Comment: Es geht darum, dass eine Person immer einen Vorsitzenden geholfen hat bis auf ein paar öffentliche Veranstaltungen.

Comment: Hat er immer dem gleichen Vorsitzenden geholfen?

Comment: Du hast den "translation" Tag gewählt. Welche Übersetzung meinst Du?

Comment: Aus welcher Sprache hast du das übersetzt?

Comment: Es wäre einfacher, dir zu helfen, wenn du etwas mehr Kontext mitliefern würdest, so ist es leider fast unmöglich

Comment: *Ausgenommen* fordert einen Akkusativ; wenn die *Veranstaltungen* die Ausnahmen sind, würde ich  *die* statt *den* erwarten, was im Plural nur beim Dativ auftritt.

Answer (score 4):

Ich tippe mal kurz und knapp auf

> Außer bei öffentlichen Veranstaltungen half er immer den Vorsitzenden.

'Ausgenommen' scheint sich nicht sehr gut auf Zeitangaben beziehen zu können und wird oft nachgestellt:

> Er half bei allen Gelegenheiten, öffentliche Veranstaltungen
>   ausgenommen.

Der letzte Satz mag möglich sein, besser finde ich eine Formulierung mit 'außer'.

Answer (score 3):

Entweder ohne *es*:

> Die öffentlichen Veranstaltungen ausgenommen, ist bekannt, dass er
>   immer den Vorsitzenden geholfen hat.

Oder den Satz weiter umgestellt:

> Es ist bekannt, dass er, die öffentlichen Veranstaltungen ausgenommen,
>   immer den Vorsitzenden geholfen hat.

oder:

> Es ist bekannt, dass er immer den Vorsitzenden geholfen hat, die
>   öffentlichen Veranstaltungen ausgenommen.

Comment: *Ausgenommen* verlangt den Akkusativ. Daher ist diese Antwort korrekt.

Answer (score 2):

Der Satz ist insofern interessant, als er komplex ist und daher dem Sprachdrechsler einiges abverlangt, will er Fehler vermeiden.

Nach Lektüre der Erläuterungen in den Kommentaren sowie unter Zuhilfenahme der Stochastik könnte man vermuten, dass etwa Folgendes gemeint war:

> Wie man weiß, hat er seinen Vorgesetzten stets geholfen, nur nicht bei einer Reihe von öffentlichen Veranstaltungen.

Dies ist eine Fassung in sehr gutem Deutsch, das in der Stilistik sich von Bürokratismen fernhält.

Je nach Kontext und sprachlichem Register oder Stilebene wären auch andere Formulierungen möglich.

> Es ist bekannt, dass er den Vorgesetzten stets geholfen hat, außer bei öffentlichen Veranstaltungen.
>
> Außer bei öffentlichen Veranstaltungen hat er den Vorgesetzten immer geholfen.
>
> Es ist bekannt, dass er den Vorgesetzten außer bei öffentlichen Veranstaltungen immer geholfen hat.
>
> Außer bei öffentlichen Veranstaltungen hat er, wie man weiß, den Vorgesetzten stets nach Kräften geholfen.

Anmerkung: Aus dem Thema des Satzes folgere ich, dass eher "den Vorgesetzten" gemeint ist, nicht etwa "den Vorsitzenden" oder "dem Vorsitzenden". Man könnte die Sätze aber schadlos auch mit *den Vorsitzenden* oder *dem Vorsitzenden* bilden.

Alle Formulierungen mit "Abgesehen von (wem oder was)" oder "Ausgenommen (wen oder was / wessen)", also zum Beispiel

> *Abgesehen von öffentlichen Veranstaltungen ist bekannt, dass er seinen Vorgesetzten immer half. [FALSCH!]

haben das unlösbare Problem, dass die "Veranstaltungen" dann syntaktisch entweder Subjekt oder Objekt des Satzes sein müssten. Also etwa:

> Abgesehen von öffentlichen Veranstaltungen hat er alles organisiert, was ihm aufgetragen wurde.

Hier sind die Veranstaltungen Objekt. (Was hat er organisiert? Die Veranstaltungen.)

> Abgesehen von öffentlichen Veranstaltungen ist uns letztes Jahr alles gelungen, was wir uns vorgenommen haben.

Hier ist "Veranstaltungen" so etwas wie eine Erweiterung des Subjekts ("alles").

Woran liegt das? Das Verb *helfen* kann ergänzt werden mit Präpositionalangaben (hier: "bei", denkbar wären auch "mit", "durch", "in" etc. je nach  Kontext) Will man also die Veranstaltungen hier einbauen, muss man es mit Präposition machen. Dann käme heraus:

> *Abgesehen von **bei** öffentlichen Veranstaltungen half er ihnen immer. [FALSCH!]

Im Englischen wäre so etwas wohl möglich (native speakers please correct me):

> Except (for) at public events he helped them at all possible occasions.

Im Deutschen klingt es jedoch zu verzwirbelt.

Comment: Es könnte der Vorsitzende eines Vereins sein. Dann würde der Satz Sinn ergeben und wäre nicht bei den Haaren herbei gezogen.

Comment: @IQV   Ja, das stimmt. Ich hatte das kurz erwogen, dann aber verworfen, weil ich meinte, solche Tätigkeitsbeurteilungen sind im Vereinsleben nicht üblich. Aber, okay, ja, es könnte sein: Aus einer Lobrede zum Abschied vom langjährigen Vereins-Faktotum (das jedoch leutescheu war und sich von Veranstaltungen fernhielt).

Comment: Es können auch Vorstandsvorsitzende sein, denen ein Lobbyist immer geholfen hat... aber ich denke, das ist unerheblich bei der Beantwortung der gestellten Frage und dass, wie auch ich schon geschrieben habe *außer bei* ganz gut klingt.

Comment: Beim Vorsitzenden denke ich irgendwie immer an "Comrade Chairman"

Comment: @tofro   Ja, darum hatte ich in einer nun jedoch gelöschten Seitenbemerkung auch gescherzt ob wohl der Vorsitzende der  Bulgarischen Kommunistischen Partei gemeint sei. Das erklärt auch wieder IQVs Einspruch gegen das Andenhaarenherbeigezogensein, das ich ins Spiel gebracht hatte.

Answer (score 2):

Warum beantwortet denn niemand die Frage?

## Zur Grammatik

Ja, «ausgenommen» ist richtig. Es liegt aber *grammatisch gesehen* ein Fallfehler vor. Es müsste ein Nominativ folgen:

> Ausgenommen die öffentlichen Veranstaltungen ist es bekannt, dass er immer den Vorsitzenden geholfen hat.

Ein Dativ gibt dem Satz eine andere Struktur, denn er impliziert eine Verwendung von «ausgenommen» als Konjunktion, die einen Nebensatz einleitet:

> … , ausgenommen deiner Mutter ist es bekannt, dass er immer den Vorsitzenden geholfen hat.

Der Satz, um den es hier geht, ist jedoch ein Hauptsatz. Subjekt ist der Nebensatz «dass er immer den Vorsitzenden geholfen hat», wie die Frageprobe zeigt:

- Wer oder was ist bekannt? – Dass er immer den Vorsitzenden geholfen hat, ist bekannt.

Das Satzteil «ausgenommen die öffentlichen Veranstaltungen» bezieht sich als Prädikativum auf das Subjekt. Das Wort «ausgenommen» fungiert als Satzteilkonjunktion, ähnlich wie «wie» oder «als». Im Unterschied zu Präpositionen regieren diese Wörter keinen Fall. Stattdessen richtet sich der Fall nach dem Bezugsatzglied (vgl. *du als der beste, dir als dem besten* usw.). Da hier das Bezugsatzglied das Subjekt ist, braucht es den Nominativ.

## Zur Bedeutung

Die ganze Phrase aus Subjekt und Prädikativum lautet wie folgt:

- dass er immer den Vorsitzenden geholfen hat, ausgenommen die öffentlichen Veranstaltungen

Zur einfacheren Analyse ersetze ich den Nebensatz durch ein einzelnes Wort:

- seine Hilfsbereitschaft, ausgenommen die öffentlichen Veranstaltungen

Es werden also die Veranstaltungen von einem Charakterzug ausgenommen. Das geht natürlich nicht. Man kann nur Gleiches von Gleichem ausnehmen, also entweder Veranstaltungen von Veranstaltungen:

- alle Veranstaltungen, ausgenommen die öffentlichen (Veranstaltungen)

… oder Charakterzüge von Charakterzügen:

- seine Hilfsbereitschaft, ausgenommen (seine Hilfsbereitschaft) bei öffentlichen Veranstaltungen

In diesem Sinn lautet der Satz wie folgt:

> Es ist bekannt, dass er immer den Vorsitzenden geholfen hat, ausgenommen bei öffentlichen Veranstaltungen.

Die Verschiebung des Prädikativums ins Vorfeld macht den Satz zwar nicht ungrammatikalisch, aber doch schwer verständlich (wie die anderen Antworten zeigen):

> Ausgenommen bei öffentlichen Veranstaltungen ist es bekannt, dass er immer den Vorsitzenden geholfen hat.

Comment: Aaah - schöne Antwort. Trés cool !

Comment: Nicht Nominativ, sondern Akkusativ muss bei *ausgenommen* stehen, was aber hier die gleiche Form ist. Siehe https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ausgenommen

Comment: Wiktionary liegt falsch, vgl. [DWDS, Lemma *ausgenommen*](https://dwds.de/wb/ausgenommen): «wird das abhängige Wort nachgestellt, so steht es im Kasus des Beziehungswortes» (inkl. schöne Beispiele mit allen Kasus).

Answer (score 0):

Nein. Das ist nicht richtig.

Leider ist der Satz so verunstaltet, dass ich nicht erkennen kann, was er eigentlich aussagen soll. Daher kann ich leider auch nicht sagen, was stattdessen richtig wäre.

Ein Wort ist auch falsch geschrieben: <del>Verantaltungen</del> richtig ist: *Veranstaltungen*

Comment: *Leider ist der Satz so verunstaltet* ist starker Tobak, das könnte man auch netter formulieren.

Comment: Den Satz als verunstaltet zu bezeichnen, impliziert, dass er zu einem früheren Zeitpunkt besser war. Wer so harsch Kritik übt, sollte auch auf sein eigenes Deutsch achten.

Comment: @CarstenS: Ja, genau das habe ich ja gemeint: Der Satz war früher vermutlich in einem besseren Zustand, nämlich als der noch in der Muttersprache des Fragestellers durch dessen Kopf ging.

Comment: Gut, dann nehme ich den Teil meiner Kritik zurück. Ich finde es aber nicht klar, dass der Satz zuerst in einer anderen Sprache existiert hat.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22724)

Comment: @userunknown: The question was: *»Ist in diesem Satz ›ausgenommen‹ richtig?«* (Literal quote from the original post.) Please explain, why *»Nein. Das ist nicht richtig.«* doesn't provide an answer to the question.